# Account locked after I deleted questions that attacked griefer?

Tags: support

Several of my questions attracted griefer who bombarded the comments with nit picks, so I deleted them, now my account is locked from making new posts because the question that are left are boring and have scores of 1 or 0 and nobody is interested in engaging with them.

Apparently the only way that I can unlock my account is to make these questions exciting enough to get noticed and up voted.

Surely this cannot be right?

How can I unlock my account when I'm not able to create new posts and my existing ones aren't getting enough engagement?

Is there another way to bring my rating up!

Comment: https://superuser.com/help/question-bans

Comment: This should be a technical forum, not a platform to chance likes, the policy disincentives asking difficult questions.

Comment: One doesn't get question banned after only a handful of poorly received questions. The fact you are question banned suggests the number of questions you have asked, that have been poorly received, is more than a handful. Deleted questions cannot receive upvotes.

Comment: @Ramhound, My questions were poorly received - by Greifers who spammed the comments with rants and off topic content - I deleted the questions and my account was locked. Your victim blaming, someone greifs my account and I get blocked, in what world is that OK? It was three questions, which isn't even a handful.

Comment: @AaarghZombies - **I am absolutely NOT victim blaming  you.** I am explaining that due to the combination of deleting your questions, other questions not receiving upvotes, and other poorly received questions is the reason you are question banned.  You can solve the situation yourself, can ask positively received questions, once every 6 months.  You should have reported the comments to a moderator instead.  Understand, I cannot support or condone these comments you talk about, since I didn't see them or even your questions. I can only explain the reason you are question banned.

Comment: @Ramhound, Sorry, but that's exactly what victim blaming is. A small number of griefers downvote spammed me. To make things worse, there is absolutely nothing on the dashboard to tell you that you're in danger of getting blocked. I can't even reverse the block by restoring and improving the questions.

Comment: @AaarghZombies - You can ask higher quality questions once every 6 months.

Comment: @Ramhound, And now I know why so many people have multiple accounts. People are just abandoning their old ones and starting over because they're not able to get a high enough ratio of likes to dislikes to maintain an account for any length of time. This system seems designed to farm softball questions that generate clicks rather than to get technical questions answered.

Comment: @AaarghZombies - Don’t create a second account to avoid a question ban. Have you flagged the unnecessary comment or requested the question to be deassociated from your account? Before you go down the path of creating another account and being suspended for trying to avoid a question ban

Answer (score 5):

Well - generally you don't want to really delete posts unless needed.

> Several of my questions attracted griefer who bombarded the comments with knit picks

Well - moderators can see deleted posts. The deleted posts were off topic, closed and the comments advised they were and why. They seem to have been ignored.

> Is there another way to bring my rating up!

Feels like the wrong thing to take away from the situation

Looking at your posts, you essentially tried to ask the same question about IOT, 3 different ways and that pushed you into a question ban. Rather than taking the comments as nit picks - taking into consideration the comments on the first attempt would have saved you from a suspension.

We'd rather help folks avoid question bans in the first place *but* I don't see the current state of the questions being fixable in a way to lift the bans, which are automatic.

I think the *important* thing here is to understand those comments are there to help, and to better familiarise yourself with the site as a whole. *Quality* content will help a lot - *good* answers (and take your time with those - we have answer bans too, and sometimes folks overeager to get a question ban lifted get those) and other positive contributions help somewhat. There's also generally an opportunity to ask questions about 3 months after a question ban, and its worth asking yourself how best to use it.

If you *get* these things, then it should be possible to pull yourself out of a question ban.